# Alert if no radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, alert

If no radio buttons was selected in 'Choose your type of pet' section after clicking on the submit button, an alert box should pop up saying "You did not select a type of pet". And same goes for the colour when radio buttons is not selected with alert 'You did not select a colour'.

Thankyou in advance

Whole html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Adopt a pet</title>
<head>
<script>
function calculateCost() {

    var radioButton;
    var checkbox;
    var pet;
    var colour;
    var cost = 0;
    
   var selectedPet = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"];
    var selectedColour = ["Black", "Gold", "White"];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedPet[i-1]);
      if (radioButton.checked == true) {
        pet = selectedPet[i-1];
        cost+= parseInt(radioButton.value);
        //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
       }
       //I just guessed this part. This may not be the correct code for this
      else if(selectedPet == null) OR (pet == null)
      alert("You did not selected a pet")
     }

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedColour[i-1]);
        if (radioButton.checked == true) {
          colour = selectedColour[i-1];
          cost+= parseInt(radioButton.value);
          //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
        }
        // This part I guessed again
        else if(selectedColour == null) OR (colour == null)
          alert("You did not selected a colour")
        }
        else
          alert("You did not select anything")
        }
      
      alert("You have selected a "+pet+" and the colour selected was "+colour+", the total cost is $"+cost);
      
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Adopt a pet </h1>
<form>
  <p>Choose a type of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="pet" value="200"><label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Dog" name="pet" value="200"><label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Rabbit" name="pet" value="20"><label for="rabbit">Rabbit</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Choose the colour of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Black" name="colour" value="80"><label for="black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="colour" value="100"><label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="White" name="colour" value="90"><label for="white">White</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="calculateCost();">
  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your console errors

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`

Comment: *"What if I want to multiply it, such as "selected pet value" x "selected colour value" = cost"* What about that? What's the question there?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Like instead of adding the selected values to find the total cost, what if I want it to multiply for e.g 20 x 80 = 8,000 (Rabbit x Black). Just need to know for another exercise.

Comment: Again, what about that. Just multiply instead of add.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected radios directly using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

You do need to make sure the values are numbers - using parseInt or just a `+`

You can leave out the form and use the button since you are not submitting.

```js
function calculateCost() {

  var cost = 0;
  var selPet = document.querySelector("[name=pet]:checked");
  var selColour = document.querySelector("[name=colour]:checked");
  var error = []; 
  if (!selPet) {
    error.push("No Pets");
  }
  if (!selColour) {
    error.push("No Colour");
  }
  if (error.length>0) {
    alert(error.join('\n')); // show one or two errors with a newline
    return; // no need to stay
  }
  // implicit else
  cost = (+selPet.value) + (+selColour.value);
  // or
  // cost = (+selPet.value) * (+selColour.value);

  alert("You have selected a " + selPet.value + 
        " and the colour selected was " + selColour.value + 
        ", the total cost is $" + cost);
}
```

```html
<h1> Adopt a pet </h1>
  <p>Choose a type of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="pet" value="200"><label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Dog" name="pet" value="200"><label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Rabbit" name="pet" value="20"><label for="rabbit">Rabbit</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Choose the colour of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Black" name="colour" value="80"><label for="black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="colour" value="100"><label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="White" name="colour" value="90"><label for="white">White</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateCost()" />
```

Here I use the submit event and a submit button since you had a form - you then need to stop the submission (by returning false) in case of error or if AJAX is used

```js
function calculateCost() {

  var cost = 0;
  var selPet = document.querySelector("[name=pet]:checked");
  var selColour = document.querySelector("[name=colour]:checked");
  if (!selPet) {
    alert("No Pets");
    return false;
  }
  if (!selColour) {
    alert("No Colour");
    return false;
  }

  cost = (+selPet.value) + (+selColour.value);
 // cost = (+selPet.value) * (+selColour.value);

  alert("You have selected a " + selPet.value + " and the colour selected was " + selColour.value + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
  return false // return true; // submits
}
```

```html
<h1> Adopt a pet </h1>
<form onsubmit="return calculateCost()">
  <p>Choose a type of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="pet" value="200"><label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Dog" name="pet" value="200"><label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Rabbit" name="pet" value="20"><label for="rabbit">Rabbit</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Choose the colour of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Black" name="colour" value="80"><label for="black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="colour" value="100"><label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="White" name="colour" value="90"><label for="white">White</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Since this `form` isn't actually submitting data to an `action` location, you really shouldn't use a `submit` button and event.

Comment: Since OP had a form, it is likely that he wants to submit the form at a certain stage. He even has `value="Submit"`. I should also not really use an inline submit handler but let's get the noob's homework look a little like he wrote it

Comment: I have updated with another snippet not using the form

Answer (score 0):

This is a whole lot simpler than what you are doing. The **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** DOM method makes getting the checked radio buttons very simple (see comments in code below):

```js
function calculateCost() {
    var cost = 0;
    
    var selectedPet = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"];
    var selectedColour = ["Black", "Gold", "White"];
    
    // Query each group for a checked radio button:
    var petRadio = document.querySelector("input[name=pet]:checked");
    var colorRadio = document.querySelector("input[name=colour]:checked");    
    
    // If each variable holds a valid reference to an element, 
    // then a pet and a color were chosen/
    if(petRadio && colorRadio){
      // A string holding a number can be converted quickly to a number by 
      // prepending a plus sign in front of it. For multiplication, just use *
      // as the operator insteach of + (the one in the middle)
      cost = +petRadio.value + +colorRadio.value;
      
      alert("You have selected a " + petRadio.id + 
            " and the colour selected was " + 
            colorRadio.id + 
            ", the total cost is $" + cost);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, one or both were not chosen
      alert("You must select a pet and a color!");
    }     
}
```

```html
<h1> Adopt a pet </h1>
<form>
  <p>Choose a type of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="pet" value="200"><label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Dog" name="pet" value="200"><label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Rabbit" name="pet" value="20"><label for="rabbit">Rabbit</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Choose the colour of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Black" name="colour" value="80"><label for="black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="colour" value="100"><label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="White" name="colour" value="90"><label for="white">White</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="calculateCost();">
  
</form>
```

Comment: Is this not almost exactly what I posted? Including the number conversion using + ? - excluding comments though

Comment: @mplungjan I did post mine after yours, but I didn't see yours because I was working on mine. Mine, does not use the submit button or submit event however and it (I believe) documents what's being done in a more detailed way than yours.

Comment: I added a version without submit after you commented on my answer - but before I saw your answer.